# Uncaught ReferenceError: writeIn is not defined at change (<anonymous>:5:4) at <anonymous>:7:1

Tags: javascript, function, web, error-handling, frontend

I try to write a function to change the color of a text, but the error occurs. I winder how to fix this.

```
function change() {
var colour = prompt("What's your favourite colour?");
a = colour.value
id = document.querySelector('.tab ');
id.style.backgoundColor = writeIn(a) ;
}
change();
console.log(a);
```

I edited the code as below, the error went, but still the value is undifined and no change occurs in the text.

```
var changing = function change() {
var cls = document.querySelector('.tab ');
var colour = prompt("What's your favourite colour?");
var a = colour.value;
cls.style.backgoundColor = a ;
alert(a);
}
changing();
console.log(a);
```

Comment: `prompt()` returns a "string". Affixing `.value` to `colour` won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of hardworking, eventually, I can solve my question and improve the code a lot. The code below works, but an error in console occurs which is not a fatal one.

```
function change(class_selector) {
 var cls = document.querySelector(class_selector);
 var colour = prompt("What's your favourite colour?");

if(colour){
 var a = document.querySelector(class_selector).innerHTML= colour;
}else{
 var a = 'blue';
}
cls.style.color = a ;
alert(a);
}
var changing = change('.s-btn__primary');
alert(colour);
console.log(a);
```

You should enter the name of the class in the function when you want to use it.
Respect to anyone who made an effort to solve this challenge.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you haven't declared **writeIn(a)** function anywhere. So this is the reason for error.

Just comment that line it will work, or declare the `writeIn` function.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful in your code. First of all you missed the ";" in the third line. In this case it's OK, but I recomment you input ";" after every instruction.

Secondly, is the `a` global variable? And id? Use at least `var`, but better `let` or `const` to declare the variables. As I undersand `id` is local and `a` is global (from the parent scope). Here you can read about [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) and [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

And about your answer: there are no function `writeIn`. You shold just assign:

```
id.style.backgoundColor = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want some thing like below code:

```js
let favouriteColor;

function change() {
  favouriteColor = prompt("What's your favourite colour?");
  cls = document.querySelector('.tab ');
  cls.style.backgroundColor = favouriteColor;
  alert(favouriteColor);
}
change();
console.log(favouriteColor);
```